# A non-abelian group of order $6$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{S}_3$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $6$ and $H$ be a non-normal subgroup of $G$ such that $|H|=2$.

Consider Action of $G$ on set of left cosets of $H$ by left multiplication. Let $\{g_iH :1\leq i\leq 3\}$ be cosets of $H$ in $G$. Then the maps : $\phi : G\rightarrow \mathcal{S}(G/H)$, $g\mapsto \sigma_g$ (such that $\sigma_g: G/H\to G/H$, $g_iH\mapsto gg_iH$) be a morphism of group of kernel
$$
\ker (\phi)=\bigcap_{i=1}^{3} g_iHg_i^{-1}
$$

**Problem** I want to show that $\ker (\phi)=\{0\}$.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Use that $H$ is non-normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You know that if $H$ isn't normal, then there is more than one conjugate subgroup. This means that for at least one $i$, $g_iHg_i^{-1} \neq H$. How many conjugate subgroups will you then have given that |H| = 2 and what will $\bigcap_{i=1}^{3} g_iHg_i^{-1}$ be?

Comment: Note also that the action by conjugation acts faithfully on the subgroups of order $2$ ($H$ is sent to each of its conjugates). $G$ can therefore be identified with $S_3$ by identifying each element of $G$ with the permutation of subgroups conjugate to $H$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lvert G\rvert=2p$ for prime $p=3$, we can use the following theorem:

> **Theorem 7.3:** Let $G$ be a group of order $2p$, where $p$ is a prime greater than $2$. Then $G$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{2p}$ or $D_p.$

*(Here $D_p$ is the dihedral group of order $2p$.)*

The theorem is fairly standard; I quoted it from page 150 of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*, but you're likely to find it in any decent textbook on group theory or abstract algebra.

Note that $S_3\cong D_3$.

Since $G$ is nonabelian (as it has a non normal subgroup), then, we have $G\cong S_3$.